# What endpoint do I use to create a Knowledge Article Version with the SOAP API?

Tags: api, soap-api, knowledge

My ultimate goal is to publish Knowledge Articles via API. I'm not exactly sure where to send the POST request, though. I tried:

```
/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Knowledge_kav
```

But I just get the reply:

```
{
  "article_response": [
    {
      "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
      "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where can I send the data so that it is actually inserted? Is my goal of posting articles via API even possible?

Edit: Adrian Larson solved it, it's __kav, two underscores.

Comment: Shouldn't it be two underscores? So `Knowledge__kav` instead of `Knowledge_kav`.

Comment: You know what, it is. Thanks! Someone at Salesforce should fix the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm), the second yellow block has it with one underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the proper suffix contains two underscore characters (`_`) where you have one. Change `Knowledge_kav` to `Knowledge__kav` and you should be all set.